# Unity3d HingeJoint

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, разработка-игр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте.

Сделал собираемый танчик, у которого модули соединяются джоинтами. Корпус и башню соединил с помощью HingeJoint (компонент висит на корпусе, конект боди башня), наверное не самый подходящий, но я не знаю какой лучше поставить, и из-за этого возникла проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда кручу корпус, башня остаётся на месте, а мне нужно чтобы она тоже крутилась вместе с ним, поэтому, так как я ничего не нашел, решил написать костыль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Частично это решило проблему, но угловые скорости корпуса и башни не совпадают и я не знаю как правильно доработать 22 строку *говно*-кода. Помогите его доработать или если вы знаете другие способы решения проблемы поделитесь пожалуйста!!!

Comment: а почему бы просто не добавлять элементы в одну группу, без джоинтов?

Comment: потому что все модули имеют компонент Rigidbody и они развалятся даже если будут в одной иерархии

Comment: а зачем всем модулям rigidbody?

Comment: Танк состоит из 4 модулей: шасси, корпус, башня, пушка. К шасси присоединён корпус с помощью FixedJoint, а к корпусу башня (HingeJoint), к башне пушка (в этом случае без разницы как она присоединена, хоть джоинтом, хоть дочерним расположением в иерархии). Когда к шасси прикладывается сила и оно начинает движение, таща на себе корпус и другие модули. Если модули(убрав Rigidbody) расположить просто в пустой GameObject с Rigidbody и прикладывать силу этому объекту, то танк тоже поедет, но если он перевернётся вверх ногами, то он продолжить ехать уже на спине. Джоинты не работают без Rigidbody.

Comment: Ну так по мимо общего `rigidbody` дающему танку динамическую физику, нужен второй на шасси и задавать силу именно ему. А скрепляются части не джоинами а иерархией вложенности объектов. Вроде... =)

Comment: если я сделаю башню дочерним по отношению к корпусу и им обоим добавлю `rigidbody` то они просто держаться не будут и упадут, поэтому я их и скрепляю джоинтами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я нашел решение проблемы спустя пару дней)))

у HingeJoint есть свойство spring которое крутит соединенный объект с определенной силой на необходимый угол, и оно является структурой JointSpring, у которого есть поля spring "сила пружины", damper, targetPosition.

Когда мы прикладываем крутящий момент (какой нибудь кнопкой) необходимо установить joint.useSpring = false,
после нужно создать экземпляр mySpring типа JointSpring (мы не можем напрямую менять поля свойства spring) в котором каждый Update() делаем mySpring.targetPosition = joint.angle "это угол на котором находится соединенного объекта" и делаем joint.spring = mySpring;

И когда ввод прекращается устанавливаем joint.useSpring = true и наш соединенный объект крутиться вместе с основанием правильно